# Need help understanding this while loop

Tags: python

In the following piece of code the while loop stops when the length of the buffer reaches 31. But for every iteration we are adding 100, so this loop should run only once.

```
buffer=["A"]
counter=100

while len(buffer) <= 30:
    buffer.append("A"*counter)
    counter=counter+200
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This loop adds to `buffer` 29 strings with repeated `A` with lengths from 100 to 5900 (each has length +200 from previous)

Comment: `>>> 'A'*10` `->` `'AAAAAAAAAA'` - when something unexpected happens, try/experiment in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding "AAAAAAAA..." every time, not 100 individual "A"'s.

Answer (score 2):

The following points should answer your question.

- Buffer is  a list.
- Every iteration of the loop you are adding a single element to the
  list.
- Every iteration the element you are adding to the list is just a
  longer string.
- len(buffer) will return the amount of items within the list.
- Because you are only adding one element (regardless of its length) to
  the list each iteration, it'll run as long as the list <= 30 elements long (i.e 31 elements)

Answer (score 0):

The condition in which this loop will continue to run is not based on `counter`, it's based on the length of the list `buffer`. `counter`'s value will have no affect on the number of iterations.

This is saying: "While the length of `buffer` is <= 30, continue running the code in the following block".

The length of buffer is increased by one each iteration, because we're appending just one value. That value happens to be a string with many `"A"`s concatenated into each other. The number of `"A"`s is determined by `counter`'s value, but we're still only adding one string to `buffer` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer=["A"]
counter=100

while len(buffer) <= 30:
    buffer.append("A"*counter)
    counter=counter+200
```

The while checks the condition for the length of the list `buffer`. When a `string` is multiplied by a scalar, then it returns that number of strings as a single `item` altogether. Hence each time the condition is checked, there is **a single item** being added, with different lengths.

For example if you try:

```
"hello"*2
```

Output:

```
hellohello
```

Which still would represent a single item in a list

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple correct answers already, but I feel that they fail to make the critical distinction clear enough for a beginner.

`buffer` starts out as `["A"]`. You seem to be under the misconception that `["A"].append(["AAAAA"])` results in `["AAAAAA"]`, when in fact it results in `["A", "AAAAA"]`. Subsequent evaluation of `len(buffer)` will yield `2`, not `6`.